# Powerpoint - embedded wmv not playing on some devices

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint, wmv

We are using MOODLE and consequently uploading current Powerpoints with embedded video within.  However, the wmvs will run on some pc's but not our laptops or on our training network.  Any ideas as to why please?

Comment: That is a Windows Media Video file, by any chance are these laptops not running Windows? Or do they not have windows media player installed?

Comment: It also is possible the training network machines have been configured in such a way that embedded videos can't be played no matter what you do.  You would have to seek help in changing that configuration within your organization.

Answer (score 0):

WMV stands for 'Windows Media Video'. If the target machines do not have a suitable player for the WMV format they probably will be incapable of playing the embedded files.

Judging from a quick google search it would appear that there are no restrictions as to what media type can be embedded in the presentation, due to this I would suggest converting the WMV files to a more portable format, such as mp4, which has much wider support.

That being said, if the only acceptable solution is for the files to remain as WMVs there are some things to check, such as if the machine is running Windows you many need to download & install [Windows Media Player](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/download-windows-media-player) if it is not already present on the machine.

If the device is running OS X you will instead need something like [Flip4Mac](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=200040), as directed by information provided on the previous link.

> Windows Media Components for QuickTime
>
> With Flip4Mac Windows Media Components for QuickTime by Telestream, you can play Windows Media files (.wma and .wmv) directly in QuickTime Player and view Windows Media content on the Internet using a web browser. To purchase Flip4Mac Player, visit the Telestream website.

Answer (score 0):

One of two reasons is responsible for this issue:

1. The different versions of the powerpoint installation are not compatible

   Solution: [Powerpoint Viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=13)

   It is supposed to play any Powerpoint presentation.
2. The presentation was created with an old (~2007) powerpoint version.

   Not even the Powerpoint Viewer Version will help here since older versions of Powerpoint just linked to the movie file and so you have to uploadthe movie file to moodle, too.

   It's advised to make a separate folder for your presentation where you put in every pasted file (movies, images...). You do not only upload the powerpoint file in this case, but the entire folder. With this method you are on the safe side.

(A missing player for a special audio or video format can't be the problem as long as there is a local powerpoint installation since powerpoint requires [several formats](https://support.office.com/en-MY/Article/Video-and-audio-file-formats-supported-in-PowerPoint-d8b12450-26db-4c7b-a5c1-593d3418fb59) natively.)